# Xcode 4.6 application launch timeout with distribution profile only

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, xcode4.6

I already read some posts regarding this issue but none seem to work for me.
I have a target using a distribution profile which worked well until recently (it worked including profiling with the leaks instrument)

But now when I try to run/profile I get the app launch timed out message.

I am running in release mode and I tried restarting the entire world (computer,device etc..) including cleaning everything as suggested but I still get this message.

I even cleared the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method just to make sure nothing heavy is happening on launch but still the launch timeout happens.

On development profiles everything works well except for profiling with leaks but that is another story I assume.

I run on **Xcode 4.6 (4H127)**

Can I only archive with the distribution or is this going to happen when Apple tests it ?

Comment: What are you doing in start up? If you are loading a storyboard - what is happening there?

Comment: Hi @Paul.s I run a cocos2d engine and I am not using storyboard but even when the applicationDidFinishLaunching method is empty (except for the basic window initialization) this still happens